# Get processname or ID from CSCore audiostream

Tags: c#, cscore

I have filtered all audio streams from my programs with CSCore lib. It works fine, but I have no idear which stream belong to which process.
Is there a way to get the processId oder processname per stream?

my code:

```
public class Audio
{
    public static void start(ListBox device, ListBox process)
    {
        using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        {

            using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
            {

                foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                    {
                        device.Items.Add(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue());

                        process.Items.Add("here I need the processname or ID");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to query an instance of the `AudioSessionControl2` object:

```
public class Audio
{
    public static void start(ListBox device, ListBox process)
    {
        using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        {

            using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
            {
                foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                    using(var session2 = session.QueryInterface<AudioSessionControl2>())
                    {
                        device.Items.Add(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue());
                        var processID = session2.ProcessID;
                        process.Items.Add("here I need the processname or ID");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```